# calling `file.show` on a directory causing crash

Tags: r, crash

I called `file.show` on a variable that contained a path instead of a file and `R` crashed.

When I brought it back up, I tested

```
 file.show("~")
```

And I get a consistent crash.

Can anyone confirm?  I'm getting an issue on both R 3.0 and R 2.15.3

---

#### R 3.0 - hangs indefinitely

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.8.8
```

---

#### R 2.15.3 - crashes and *cannot* gracefully abort

```
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: Running R 3.0.0 on Windows XP, I just get a pop-up window informing me of an "Error opening file". I click "OK" and return to my R session already in progress.

Comment: No problem on `R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01) Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)`

Comment: Generally there is little action on crashes using old versions of R. You are expected to stay current.

Comment: @Dwin, I'm seeing the issue is on both 3.0 & 2.15.3

Comment: I have the exact same sessionInfo() as you do for R 3.0.0 and I have no problem. It shows an empty file and I can quit by typing `q`.

Comment: Is `getOption("pager")` giving you the default function? The one with the following synopsis: `function(files, header, title, delete.file)`

Comment: @flodel I've got `"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/pager"`

Comment: ah. nevermind, I do as well. What I was showing above is what I have under Rstudio. I'm running out of ideas... Have you tried rebooting?!

Comment: @flodel, haha, yep.  I've tried rebooting, reinstalling. Honestly, it's not the biggest deal.  Just something I encountered by accident and was wondering if it was worth submitting

Comment: OK on W7 64 bit, Rstudio 0.97.336. R is 2.15.3.

Comment: Thanks @all for testing.  Looks like it may be something specific to my system then